# SQL - Inner join to exclude rows

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following tables in a laravel application:

```
basket
------
id  PK
user_id FK
coupon_id FK

basket_items
------------
id PK
basket_id FK
product_id FK
quantity 
purchaseable_id   
purchaseable_type -- e.g. App\Job, App\CV

products
--------
id PK
name  -- e.g. standard job listing, premium job listing, cv download
price

jobs
----
id PK
product_id FK
title
start_dt
expiry_dt
description

cvs
------
id PK
name
```

The `purchaseable_id` and `purchaseable_type` in the `basket_items` table are polymorphic relationships. E.g. a user can add a job to their basket which is a premium product listing - the purchaseable_id in this case would be the id of the job from the jobs table and the purchaseable_type would be `App\Job`. Sample rows in the basket_items table may look like the following:

```
id | basket_id | product_id | quantity | purchaseable_id | purchaseable_type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1         |  1         |   1      |     1           | App\Job   
2  | 1         |  3         |   1      |     1           | App\CV
```

I want a to list all basket_items for a user but exclude items if the purchaseable_type is `App\Job` and the job has expired.

I have tried the following but it excludes all rows if the job has expired i.e. it excludes items of every purchaseable_type

```
select t1.*, t2.* 
from baskets t1
inner join basket_items t2 on t2.basket_id = t1.id
left join jobs t3 on t3.id = t2.purchaseable_id and t2.purchaseable_type = 'App\\Job' 
where t1.user_id = 1 and t3.expiry_dt > now()
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a left join, all the fields in the table that are not matched by the join condition are `NULL`. So in this case, when your join from `basket_items` to `jobs` does not match the join condition the fields pulled from `jobs` are all `NULL`. Since the expression `t3.expiry_dt > now()` will always return `false` if `t3.expiry_dt` is `NULL`, you will not get those records back.

A way around it is to change your WHERE clause to allow the NULLs:

```
where t1.user_id = 1 and ( t3.expiry_dt > now() OR t3.expiry_dt IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't join the jobs table. You only want to use it as criteria, so it belongs in `WHERE` or `ON`:

```
select *
from baskets b
join basket_items bi 
  on bi.basket_id = b.id
  and not
  (
    bi.purchaseable_type = 'App\Job' and
    bi.purchaseable_id in (select id from jobs where expiry_dt > now())
  )
where b.user_id = 1;
```

This gets your query more readable and hence less prone to (future) errors, i.e. provides better maintainability.

Comment: your solution is doing two queries which inefficient. The basket only needs to do a left join where there are job items in the basket. It maybe more readable but less efficient. Imagine if I have thousands of jobs.

Comment: No. The query does exactly the same, so a DBMS can actually use the same execution plan. It boils down to how the DBMS handles things internally and we shouldn't make too many assumptions about this (especially as this can change from version to version). The job subquery has to be executed only once and its result has to be looked up for only the few records of user 1 that have a purchaseable_type = 'App\Job'. That should be quick. Write your queries as readable as possible. Only when you actually do have issues, try ways around them (such as your half anti-join).

Comment: From a performance point of view: your outer join gets you more records then needed (which you dismiss in the where clause). So if the DBMS follows your instructions directly (which it doesn't have to internally) it will build a bigger intermediate result than necessary, which is something that should be avoided. But as mentioned, the DBMS' optimizer should be able to judge a query, see the risks, and decide for the best execution plan.

Comment: if I only have lets say between 1-10 job items in the basket_items table which always going to be the real world scenario then the outer join would only need to get those handful of record. The job subquery in your solution has to do a full table scan which could possibly contain thousands of records?

Comment: You are making assumptions about DBMS internals again. So my query needs to read the whole job table but yours doesn't? As mentioned, the DBMS is free to choose any execution plan it thinks best for the query. It may read the whole job table in my query and it may do it in yours, it may use a nested loop instead in my query and it may do so in yours. It may do a join instead. In your query. In mine. We don't know how the DBMS optimizer works exactly (but well, you can look at the explain plan, so at least you know what plan it choses today with the current data in the current DBMS version).